# NameError from Python input() function

Tags: python, python-2.5

```
input_var = input ("Press 'E' and 'Enter' to Exit: ")

NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

I am using Python 2.5. How I can overcome this error?

Comment: @ShinTakezou: if that works fine for you, you're not using Python 2.5.

Comment: @Wooble using python 2.5 r25:51908 (but it would be the same with 2.7) and guess: it works just fine. In fact the problem is not the line itself (but the provided input and the wrong usage of the `input`)... there's a rude answer for that, it's rtfm, I've just avoided that, but can I politely pour the doubt so that people may think they need to inspect the problem more deeply to get what's going on while waiting for an actual help? I did so, or so I think. Very likely, failed. Enlightening it's such a hard matter.

Comment: The whole issue is `input()` in Python 2. If you type `e` at the prompt, you *will* get an error, so it doesn't "work fine".

Comment: If everyone would just read the manual, and could work out which sections of which manual to read, 90% of SO would evaporate. ;)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`input` reads and evaluates a Python expression.   When it tries to evaluate it, it looks for a variable `e`, which is not defined, and fails.

You almost always want to use `raw_input` instead.  (And [in Python3, `input` has this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/243712).)

Or, better, on Unix, use [readline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) so the user can edit their input.