# Only allow user to input certain words

Tags: python

This is not working,
Cant figure it out...
i want it to print either error sentence or break..
I wanted to do it in a try/except, but that was not so good.
And I'm new to python :-)

```py
    while True:  
        unitFrom = input("Enter unit of temperature, either Fahrenheit, Kelvin or Celsius:") 
        list = ["Fahrenheit" , "Celsius" , "Kelvin"]
        if unitFrom.lower() in list:
            break
        else:
            print ("Wrong unit, try again")
            break
```

Comment: never use the keyword `list` to define your lists

Comment: Never use inbuilt declarations to define new variables. You should change 'list' to something else, since `list` is itself an inbuilt function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Never use the built-in keywords to define new variables.
2. Take the list outside the loop to avoid initializing it on each iteration.
3. You need to have the list in lowercase since you're checking the lower-cased input in the list:

Hence:

```
x_units = ["fahrenheit" , "celsius" , "kelvin"]
# or x_units = [x.lower() for x in x_units] if you do not wish to change the original list
while True:  
    unitFrom = input("Enter unit of temperature, either Fahrenheit, Kelvin or Celsius:") 
    if unitFrom.lower() in x_units:
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong unit, try again")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to print break or want to execute `break` ?
and
`list = ["Fahrenheit" , "Celsius" , "Kelvin"]` is created  new everytime
execute it before `while True:` and use something other than list as array name as `list` is a keyword

```
  answer_list = ["Fahrenheit" , "Celsius" , "Kelvin"]
while True:  
    unitFrom = input("Enter unit of temperature, either Fahrenheit, Kelvin or Celsius:") 
  
    if unitFrom.lower() in answer_list:
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong unit, try again")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not using lowercase units. And then checking if `"Kelvin" =="kelvin"`, which is never `True`.

Replace your list of units with lowercase or just use this code:

```
while True:  
    unitFrom = input("Enter unit of temperature, either Fahrenheit, Kelvin or Celsius:") 
    myList = ["Fahrenheit" , "Celsius" , "Kelvin"]
    myList = [unit.lower() for unit in myList] #transform all strings inside list to lowercase
    
    if unitFrom.lower() in myList:
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong unit, try again")
        break
```

Also never use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @dirtybit, you should take care of those points.

Set Access is faster than list, if list is of big size, you can try `set` to compare with input.

#### Solution :

```py
units_set = set("fahrenheit" , "felsius" , "kelvin") # initializing it only once, the lower case values.
while True:  
    unit_from = input("Enter unit of temperature, either Fahrenheit, Kelvin or Celsius:") 
    if unit_from.lower() in units_set:
        # do something here.
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong unit, try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
loopBool = True
while loopBool:
    unitList = ["fahrenheit", "celsius", "kelvin"]
    try:
            unitFrom = raw_input("Enter unit of temperature, either Fahrenheit, Kelvin or Celsius:")
            if unitFrom in unitList:
                inBool = True
            if  inBool == True:
               print("Success")
               loopBool = False
            else:
                raise Exception
    except:
            print ("Wrong unit, try again")
```

The problem might be input() function you use.

I do not want to change your code to much (You should think about lower in my case)

```
while True:
    unitFrom = raw_input("Enter unit of temperature, either Fahrenheit, Kelvin or Celsius:")
    unitList = ["Fahrenheit", "Celsius", "Kelvin"]
    if unitFrom in unitList:
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong unit, try again")
        break
```

You can read further about it : [NameError from Python input() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457441/nameerror-from-python-input-function)